# Firemonkey FMX.Android Intents not working properly when using chrome

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I have followed the steps in this [link](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Sydney/en/FMX.Android_Intents_Sample) to create a sample Firemonkey app that receives an intent. The app works fine with all applications but Chrome. Most of the time, Chrome seems to create a "second instance" of the application as you can see in the following screenshot:

[image]

In the left side is the main app and in the right side is Chrome after selecting "Share" and selecting the app from the list of available apps that can receive the intent. As you can see in the picture, Chrome is somehow displaying the icon of the app inside of itself and remains unresponsive. With all other apps, usually the app is shown as the active app (foreground) and displays the data it received but with Chrome, 95% of the time, I have this issue. Is there any reason why this is happening only with Chrome?